# How to use anova() on regression models with missing data?

Tags: r, regression, lm, anova

I am trying to run anovas on regression models (LMERs) with 200-400 observations, so I don't want to drop observations based on any missing data.

Here is the problem I am facing, simplified and reproducible:

```
dats <- data.frame(y = c(5, 3, 7, 4, 8, 4, 7, 3, 6, 3),
                   x = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
                   z = c(NA, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2))

fit1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = dats, na.action = "na.omit")
fit2 <- lm(y ~ x + z, data = dats, na.action = "na.omit")

anova(fit1, fit2)
```

And the error I encounter:

`Error in anova.lmlist(object, ...) : models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset`

Mainly, I need to run these ANOVAs to know whether the changes in the marginal R^2 in the LMERs are statistically significant. Is there any way of running these regressions and ANOVAs withouth dropping observations with missing data?

Comment: The answer is no I think. Maybe you could multiple time randomly delete a value in x and do the anova

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm more of a Bayes person and don't really like the NHST world view.

Like @denis, I'm pretty sure the answer is "no".  ANOVA is designed to be used on the same data as it's notionally based on comparing sum-of-squares errors.

The obvious options would be to exclude the same rows:

```
d2 <- na.omit(dats[,c('x','y','z')])

f1 <- lm(y ~ x, data=d2)
f2 <- lm(y ~ x + z, data=d2)

anova(f1, f2)
```

which obviously throws away data, or your could impute the missing data:

```
i <- na.action(d2)
d3 <- dats
d3$z[i] <- predict(lm(z ~ x*y, dats), dats[i,])

f1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = d2)
f2 <- lm(y ~ x + z, data = d2)

anova(f1, f2)
```

but this will underestimate the variance.

Comment: note that there are lots of packages for doing the imputation betterer (e.g. [see here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/dealing-with-missing-data-using-r-3ae428da2d17)), the above is just something easy in "base R"